# pandas fillna not working

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with nans in it:

```
>>>df.head()
Out[1]: 
            JPM US SMALLER COMPANIES C ACC
1990-01-02                             NaN
1990-01-03                             NaN
1990-01-04                             NaN
1990-01-05                             NaN
1990-01-08                             NaN
```

I have another dataframe with values in it:

```
>>>t.head()
Out[1]: 
1990-01-02    51.95
1990-01-03    52.63
1990-01-04    53.04
1990-01-05    52.07
1990-01-08    51.73
Name: JPM US SMALLER COMPANIES C ACC, dtype: float64
```

Unfortunately, df.fillna does not appear to be working for me:

```
>>>df.fillna( t ).head()
Out[1]: 
            JPM US SMALLER COMPANIES C ACC
1990-01-02                             NaN
1990-01-03                             NaN
1990-01-04                             NaN
1990-01-05                             NaN
1990-01-08                             NaN

[5 rows x 1 columns]
```

Why is this happening? I am on pandas 0.13.1

Comment: Oops.  I fixed it. df should have been a series, not a dataframe.  After that it worked.

Comment: In the case where you are using a DataFrame, you can use DataFrame.where to use another frame's values to replace the values when null.

Comment: @benjwadams I think in that situation it might be better to use [combine_first](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) or [update](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html). They're custom built for that purpose, so they should help you avoid errors.

Answer (score 87):

You need `inplace=True`

```
df[1].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: you helped me avoiding creating so many new objects in my pandas project.

Comment: Why is `inplace=True` needed here?

Comment: so that `df` object is modified **inplace** instead of creating a copy of it and modifying this one

Comment: Can you use `df = df.fillna(0)` instead of using `inplace`?

Comment: `inplace` will be depreceated, `df = df.fillna(0)` is the recommended usage. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529

Answer (score 9):

**Alternativly**:

`df = df.replace(np.nan, 0)` #or any other value you deem fit

df.replace(np.nan, 0) or df.fillna(0) threw me off when I applied certain str.replace()-operations right after Na-operations.. **so watch out for your order of commands -> first str.replace() than fillna()**

Answer (score 5):

You need to assign the value `df = df.fillna(t)`

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

1) Specific for each column

```
cols_fillna = ['column1','column2','column3']
# replace 'NaN' with zero in these columns
 for col in cols_fillna:
     df[col].fillna(0,inplace=True)
     df[col].fillna(0,inplace=True)
```

2) For the entire dataframe

```
df = df.fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this why `fillna()` while iterating over columns does not work.
Create a `DataFrame` with columns and check the output of following:

```
    for col in df.columns[df.isnull().any()]:
        df[col].fillna(df[col].mode(), inplace = True)
        #df[col].fillna(df[col].mode()[0], inplace = True)
        print(df[col].mode())
        #print(df[col].mode()[0])
        print(type(df[col].mode()))
        #print(type(df[col].mode()[0]))
    df.isnull().sum() / df.shape[0] * 100
```

Earlier one does not throw an error but was not filling NA values. Commented lines seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that this is because the mode() function of pandas now outputs a dataframe with two columns.

So if you don't add the [0] as in `df[col].fillna(df[col].mode()[0], inplace = True)`, the fillna() won't work because the mode() function doesn't return a scalar.

Comment: df[col].mode() returns a Series, not a dataframe. Please edit the answer.