# how to modify dataframe when referring them through a list loop

Tags: python

I have many dataframes and I store them in a list.

Now I'd like to do simple `fillna(0)` to each dataframe, so I do the following, but it didn't work:

```
df_list = [df_1,df_2,df_3,df_4]

for df in df_list:
    df = df.fillna(0)
    df.index = df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

I think df on the left hand side inside the loop is not the same as original dataframe, how to do it?

Comment: This is a duplicate. Better dupe target: [pandas fillna not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147707/pandas-fillna-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first line of the loop you are defining a new dataframe and doing nothing with it.

Instead you can just use `inplace = True` to do the work on the dataframe without creating a new one.

```
for df in df_list:
    df.fillna(0, inplace = True)
    df.index=df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Thank you Pepsi-joe

Comment: Some further reading for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893457/understanding-inplace-true

Comment: Thank you Pepsi-joe, if we use dictionary like this, for (key,df) in df_dict.items():  # not just items, use iterms()
    df_dict[key]=df.fillna(0), why original df don't change, but returned df using df_dict[key] change?